# UTF-8 is not work in vsmoraes/laravel-pdf 1.0.1

Tags: php, pdf, utf-8

I have just work with laravel 5, and now I want to use dompdf to work with laravel 5 too. Surely, I can use it to convert my html to pdf successfully. But the problem I encounter is about UTF-8. I can only get English language, but not my own language.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>លីណា</p>
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function pdf()
{
    $html = view('pdfs.pdf')->render();
    return PDF::load($html)->filename('lina.pdf')->show();
}
```

**dompdf font family cache**

```
'khmer-os' =>
array (
  'bold' => DOMPDF_DIR . '/lib/fonts/Battambang-Bold',
  'normal' => DOMPDF_DIR . '/lib/fonts/Battambang',
),
```

I guess I need to loan new font in dompdf->lib->font, but I don't know how to do that. Or you have other ways to make UTF-8 work with this.

Thank you for your review.

Comment: Did u find a solution to this? I am stuck at the same.